# Binding string format not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

I have an application which when started the user needs to pick a course theme and a course name. The course themes are gathered from a folder within the application data folder for the software.

I want to display the themes like Office does in Word for example where you get a choice of templates to start with. Within the theme folder is a png which is a picture of the theme I want to display. If I copy and paste the direct path like so:

```
<Image Width="600" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Source="C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Jenison\Perform\Themes\TemplateThemes\JenisonOnyxFullScreen\thumbnail.png"    />
```

It works fine. But obviously each user will have a different user name so I cannot do it this way. So I am trying this way:

```
  <Image Width="600" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ThumbnailPath, StringFormat='pack://application:,,,/Themes/TemplateThemes/{0}'}"   />
```

The binding ThumbnailPath returns JenisonOnyxFullScreen\thumbnail.png so the above is pack://application:,,,/Themes/TemplateThemes/JenisonOnyxFullScreen\thumbnail.png and I have also added this to a textblock and the path appears to be fine. But the image does not show this way.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you not bind source to a DataContext property ?

Comment: try add an ID for your Image and add Source in codebehind c#..

Comment: I think I will have to end up doing that but with the way everything is done it will take quite a bit of work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work colleague suggested something which worked perfectly first time. I added an eventsetter to the image like so:

```
   <Image Width="450" Height="400"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Image">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ThemeImagePath">

                                    </EventSetter>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
```

Then in the codebehind added a method called ThemeImagePath

```
    public void ThemeImagePath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Image = (Image)sender;
        var Theme = Image.DataContext as IPerformTheme;
        Image.Source = ImageHelper.BitmapSourceFromPath(new Uri(Model.ApplicationRoots.ThemeRoot + "/TemplateThemes/" + Theme.Name + "/thumbnail.png")); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Image Binding with string formate solved like this

```
 <Image x:Name="im" Width="600" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Source="{Binding ElementName=test, Path=Text}"    />

  <TextBlock x:Name="test" Background="Red" Text="{Binding ThumbnailPath, StringFormat=pack://application:\,\,\,/WpfApplication1;component/Images/\{0\}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43"/>
```

Comment: I've already answered my question. Tested the above anyway and it does not work